# Javascript - making 2 setInterval() be synchronous

Tags: javascript

I have 2 functions calling setInterval but I need them to be synchronous. Here is my code(yes, they are really simple).

```
var number1 = 0;

function caller(){
  go();
  come();
}

function go() {
  anim1 = setInterval("doActionGo()", 20);
}

function come() {
  anim2 = setInterval("doActionCome()", 20);
}

function doActionGo(){
  if(number1 < 1023) {
    number1++;
  } else {
    clearInterval(anim1);
  }
}

function doActionCome() {
  if (number1 > 0) {
    number1 = number1 - 1
  } else {
   clearInterval(anim2); 
}
```

functions doActionGo() and doActionCome() would be any code. Does anybody know how to solve it?

Regards!

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded, therefore "synchronous" in the "normal" way isn't even possible in the first place, what exactly are you trying to do? PS: Don't use strings in setInterval/setTimeout, see: http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#other.timeouts

Comment: i dont see that as possible. one goes then the next, it will always be off by something

Comment: doActionGo() and doActionCome() use some variable in common. These variables are being mixed in these functions.

Comment: Can you combine the go and come functions?  If they are called immediately after each other perhaps they don't need to be separate...?

Comment: @Dan Baylis: go() takes about 3 seconds, but it's not definitive, can be some more or less time. That's the reason.

Comment: @Claudio: Why can't `go` call `come`?  Or why can't you do it the way @6502 suggests?

Comment: @Rocket: I've changed the code. See now? It's because of animation.

Comment: @Claudio: Maybe you should think about using different variables for each method.

Comment: Is `clearInterval(anim)` meant to be instead `clearInterval(anim1)`? Is `if (number > 0)` meant to be instead `if (number1 > 0)`?

Comment: May be you are misusing the word "synchronous" to mean instead the opposite (i.e. "in sequence")? In other words may be you want one part of the animation to complete before starting the other part?

Comment: @6502: i'm sorry about my mistakes in this code. Yeah, I meant "in sequence", exactly what you said.

Comment: @Claudio: I'm still not sure what you are trying to do.  When this code runs `number1` will be zero which is less than 1023 which means it will be incremented (by `doActionGo`), then decremented (by `doActionCome`) because 1 is greater than zero.  Some actual code may be helpful, so maybe we can think of a better way to solve this issue.

Comment: @Rocket: It's a bit tricky to get this problem. Try to put an alert() after increment and another alert() after decrement in this same code. You will see that number1 will start increment and decrement at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To execute two animations in sequence just start the second one at the end of the first... for example:

```
var anim1, anim2;
var number = 0;

function animation1()
{
    number = number + 1;
    if (number > 1000)
    {
        clearInterval(anim1);
        anim2 = setInterval(animation2, 20);
    }
}

function animation2()
{
    number = number - 1;
    if (number < 0)
    {
        clearInterval(anim2);
    }
}

function start()
{
    anim1 = setInterval(animation1, 20);
}
```

Comment: I'm avoiding to put my entire code because it's rally complex and long. What I put here is just a easier way to understand what I need. I need a call in sequence like I did in caller() (first go() and come() ).

Answer (score 2):

Here is way to call them in sequence:

```
var number1 = 0;

function caller(){
  go( come );
}

function go(comeFn) {
    var anim = setInterval(function(){
        if(number1 < 100) {
            number1++;
        } else {
            clearInterval(anim);
            comeFn();
        }
    }, 20);
}

function come() {
    var anim = setInterval(function(){
        if (number1 > 0) {
            number1--;
        } else {
            clearInterval(anim); 
        }
    }, 20);
}
```

And two comments:

- you shouldn't use strings in `setInterval('functionName', 30)` but directly functions
- if you don't use `anim1` instead of `var anim1` it is considered as a global variables

Answer (score 0):

[**See demo of the following →**](http://jsfiddle.net/rTQGY/1/)

It wasn't really clear what you were asking, but it inspired me to write this mini animation queue.  Maybe you or someone else will benefit from it:

```
var number1 = 0,
    number2 = 1023,
    queue = [];

// execute every XX miliseconds
function tick(delay) {

    // iterate through queue
    for (var i = 0, il = queue.length; i < il; i++) {

        if (queue[i]) {

            // execute each tick function
            queue[i].tick();

        }

    }

    // recall tick
    setTimeout(function() {
        tick(delay);
    }, delay);
}

// kill tick function of matching name
function qKill(name) {
    for (var i = 0, il = queue.length; i < il; i++) {
        if (queue[i]) {
            if (queue[i].name === name) {
                queue.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}

var go = {
    name: 'go',
    tick: function() {
        if (number1 < number2) {
            number1++;
            // do whatever here
        } else {
            qKill('go');
        }
    }
};

var come = {
    name: 'come',
    tick: function() {
        if (number2 > number1) {
            number2 = number2 - 1;
            // do whatever here
        } else {
            qKill('come');
        }
    }
};

queue.push(go);
queue.push(come);

tick(20);
```

[**Demo →**](http://jsfiddle.net/rTQGY/1/)

Answer (score 0):

As people already commented, JavaScript is single threaded. So running two functions simultaneously  is impossible. However a couple of strategies can be used to simulate this.

1. For GUI effects, interpolation can be used. Basically, a single function is responsible of transitioning things step by step by interpolating the start and end value(be it an opacity, a position, a variable, a state or whatever can be interpolated). A javascript library can use this simple concept to create effects for example.
2. A second approach is to use co-routines available in javascript since version 1.7. This article (although a little old) describes [how to simulate threading in javascript](http://www.neilmix.com/2007/02/07/threading-in-javascript-17/) and can be a good starting point to understand the mechanism involved in a co-routine powered design.

Hope this will help :)